# How to execute a builtin shell command using find?

Tags: find, tcsh, shell-builtin

I'm constrained to doing this in tcsh on CentOS due to the environment at work. When executing `find . -type f -executable -exec source '{}' \;` the only result is `find: 'source': No such file or directory` for each appropriate file.  Not sure why this isn't working in tcsh as it's pretty straightforward. What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

`source` is a shell builtin. `find` executes commands. It cannot execute a shell builtin.

If you want to execute external programs, just specify the program name:

```
find . -type f -executable -exec '{}' \;
```

If these are all csh scripts lacking a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) like (`#!/bin/env csh` as the first line), add a shebang line. If you really can't add a shebang line, call csh explicitly:

```
find . -type f -executable -exec tcsh '{}' \;
```

If these are all csh script fragments that you want to execute inside the current shell, you can't do it this way. You'll need to collect the names with `find` and then source them.

```
foreach fragment ("`find . -type f -executable -print`")
  source "$fragment"
end
```

There's something fishy about this requirement in the first place. Shell fragments meant to be sourced should not be executable.

Comment: didn't realize that about find -exec and shell builtins. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score -3):

See this:

```
127:2:1389633116:user@host:~$ tcsh source foo
source: No such file or directory.
1:3:1389633119:user@host:~$ tcsh
host:~> source foo
foo: No such file or directory.
host:~> exit
0:4:1389633582:user@host:~$ tcsh -c 'source foo'
foo: No such file or directory.
```

Try those yourself, and others. Maybe inspecting `strace` traces. Finally try to take advantage and build a workaround.

Comment: I have no idea where you're getting at with this answer.

Comment: I'm telling the questioner to do `$ find . -type f -executable -exec tcsh -c 'source {}' \;`

Comment: The comment answer above is exactly what I was after, combined with the insight about shell builtins and exec from the first answer completely answers my question. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome, wherever you are!